# Persisting text as byte array to flat file

Tags: c#, .net, text

**Update**

This is to hide my public key on the client side to make it slightly more difficult for prying eyes to get to it. Yes I know the intent of the public key is to stay public but I am trying to mitigate key substitution attacks and in addition to obfuscation, assembly merging, assembly signing and some other measures this is a part of the overall strategy. So in my code that gets shipped to the client side I want to be able to do something like this

```
string publicKey = @"random characters" //don't want this in the code
byte[] keyBytes = [............] //this should be in the code
```

I am not quite sure how do I take the text of my public key, convert it to a byte array and then use that in the client code to convert back into public key.

I reckon there is an easy way to do this but I am going round in circles trying to figure it out.

Essentially I have a series of text data which I want to be able to save as bytes to a flat file. I can read it as a byte array but when I use a BinaryWriter to write that byte array to a file I end up with the original text.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Isn't that because the thing you're using to open the file is then reading it in as text because it is just text?

Comment: Agree with @codecaster answer.

Comment: Are you trying to encrypt or encode the contents? 'cause otherwise this is the expected behavior as described by @codecaster

Comment: My bad actually. I have updated the problem to explain what it is exactly that I want to achieve.

Comment: A BinaryWriter is not what its name may suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a little converter for this purpose.

```
string publicKey = "AsdfsSDhysffsdfsdfZ09";
Console.Write("byte[] keyBytes = { ");
Console.Write(String.Join(", ", Array.ConvertAll(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(publicKey), b => String.Format("0x{0:X2}", b))));
Console.WriteLine("};");
```

Run it. Then just copy the last line of the output to your source code.

Comment: PERFECT! I changed ASCII to UTF8 but this is just what I wanted!

Comment: An alternative would be to use a base-64 string: `string obfuscatedKey = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(publicKey)); string backAgain = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(obfuscatedKey));`.

Answer (score 4):

Just as every file, a text file *is* a binary file.

It just happens to be that in this case every binary number corresponds with a character, so when you open the file in a text editor, you see readable text.

Obligatory [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Thanks. I kind of understand that but my problem is to get around this temporarily. I have updated my question to clarify what I am after.

Comment: So your question is _"How to securely transfer plain text"_? Then your answer is _"By encrypting it"_.

Comment: Respectfully I don't want advise on how do I securely transfer plain text. I know that, I understand that. My specific problem in this case is to be able to convert a text to byte array and use that in the code. Would be grateful if we just focus on that.

Comment: Thanks. This assumes a file with the plain text in it to be present at the client. This is precisely what I am trying to avoid. I want the text's byte representation hard coded (then split and obfuscated etc.) in the code. The problem is how do I get that byte representation hard-coded in the code.

Comment: Now I get it. Then you need to obfuscate your assembly. Note that this will still enable someone to see the actual string, if they're persistent enough.

Comment: So you want something like `string.Join(", ", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("your string"))`? -- (or just `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("your string")`, to be precise)

Comment: @CodeCaster absolutely. The assembly will be obfuscated, strong named, signed and even merged with the other assemblies in the project to ship one consolidated unit. As I said this is one of the steps I am putting in place in addition to the other best practices. Of course someone persistent enough would get to it but I don't want to make their task easy :)